# How to get messages from other telegram bot in real time on Python?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have in my contacts list a telegram bot which sends me messages. This bot is not mine.

I want to parse these messages from other bot in real-time. How I can do this?
I want to do something like this:

```html
while True:
  got_message =  check_updates()
  if (got_message==True):
    // do something with message
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about using your own bot to parse messages from other bots, sorry the Telegram Bot API does not send you the updates of other bots.

But if you really want to manipulate with other bots' messages programmatically, you may want to try out [Telethon](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=lonamiwebs%20telethon&oq=lonamiwebs%20telethon&aqs=chrome..69i57.2545j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) logging in as yourself (yes your number) using the Telegram (not bot) API.

Answer (score 0):

you already received a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47047118/8372336).
I would like to point out an hack to make more bots talk together: Using a channel. In channels bots can see other bots messages